# Imagick constructor crashes PHP/CGI

Tags: php, crash, nginx, imagick

When I call the Imagick constructor PHP/CGI crashes.

The imagick .dll is loaded in the php.ini file (extension) and I've got imagick installed.

I am using EngineX (NGINX) and PHP 5.3.4.

I am using thread safe version of PHP and Imagick.dll (ext)

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: ImageMagick version  ImageMagick 6.6.6-5 2010-12-12 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org

Answer (score 0):

Check which compiler your version of PHP is compiled with. If you're using the Imagick dll file from the author it will be compiled with VC9. You need to have a version of PHP that is also compiled with VC9 for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have different compilers for imagick and php as Jeremy said. You can check your compiler with `echo phpinfo();`
There is good instruction (but this guy use apache)
hxxp://jeremycook.ca/2010/06/06/installing-imagick-under-apache-on-windows/

There is an IMPORTANT note. As they said ImageMagick 6.6.6-5 is compiled with VC10. So if you make as in instruction i give, it will be crashed anyway. To fix it use ImageMagick-6.6.2-Q16 (this build is the last that works for me. Seems it compiled with VC9).

look here for old releases
hxxp://image_magick.veidrodis.com/image_magick/binaries/
ftp://ftp.imagemagick.org/pub/ImageMagick/

I make this stuff works just a couple hours ago :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. What helped was switching to the latest beta version. In unix you use pecl install imagick-beta