# imagick crash with PHP 5.3

Tags: php, windows, imagick

I'm getting this error:

> The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

This only occurs when I try to load an image using ImageMagick.

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: text/html');
$image = 'some_image.jpg';

/*** a new imagick object ***/
$im = new Imagick();

/*** ping the image ***/
$im->pingImage($image);

/*** read the image into the object ***/
$im->readImage( $image );

/**** convert to png ***/
$im->setImageFormat( "png" );

/*** write image to disk ***/
$im->writeImage( '/tmp/new.png' );

echo 'Image Converted';  
?>



vertrigo serv
php 5.3.8
php_imagick_ts.dll
```

Apparently same problem here: 
http://valokuva.org/?page_id=50

I can get it loaded, phpinfo displays imagick information, but when trying to read an image Apache crashes.

Any idea about this problem?

Comment: Do your logs happen to give any clues?

Comment: Imagick is a pain to get working on 32/64 Windows. 5.3+ is practically impossible to work. Imagick was exactly the reason why I switched from Windows for development. That and a ridiculous DateTime bug that only happened in Windows.

Comment: Where did you get the *php_imagick_ts.dll* file? Does it come with VertrigoServ?

Comment: no. download from http://valokuva.org/builds/ and copy to ext folder. @Layke, i think you need something like `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');
$tz = date_default_timezone_get();`

Comment: Those are VC9 builds. You'd need to verify that your PHP binaries are VC9 as well. Good old [phpinfo()](http://php.net/phpinfo) will suffice.

Comment: PHP binaries are VC9 too. God, imagick is the devil.

Comment: Which compiler has been used to compile your webserver? The other suggestion is to use `realpath` on filenames first.

Comment: I "heard" doing some search that this could be possibly a real BUG without workout. Everyone having the same problem switched to Linux to have this solved.

Comment: I have detailed the correct installation procedure for an other question, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036847/how-to-install-imagemagick-on-windows-7#22210399).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is similar problem: [Imagick constructor crashes PHP/CGI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480180/imagick-constructor-crashes-php-cgi)

I've had the same issue today. You have to install version of Image Magick no higher than 6.6.4.0 - next builds are made using VC10 which seems to be incompatible with Apache VC9 + PHP5.3.x VC9.

Some comments on this: http://valokuva.org/?p=161#comment-20707

You can get older releases of Image Magick here: http://image_magick.veidrodis.com/image_magick/binaries/

And remember to reboot windows after installing Image Magick

Comment: +1 this worked for me on Windows 7 with xampp: http://image_magick.veidrodis.com/image_magick/binaries/ImageMagick-6.6.4-0-Q16-windows-dll.exe and http://valokuva.org/builds/ext/vc9/ts/imagick/2011-04-25_1849/php_imagick_ts.dll (renamed it to php_imagick.dll and added it to /xampp/php/ext)

Comment: The provided link to older releases no longer exists. someone help? i don't know where to find

Comment: Found something there: ftp://mirror.imagemagick.org/pub/ImageMagick/legacy/ Give it a try and tell us if it worked

Comment: If you are looking for a mirror for older releases, here you have one: ftp://ftp.sunet.se/pub/multimedia/graphics/ImageMagick/binaries/

Answer (score 1):

I just got the same error in my new server, if using PHP "new Imagick("$imagebath")"

the fix is:

set "php.ini" "memory_limit = 256M" (or more, it was 128, it's not enough), error log: "Out of memory in UB xxx: OOM killed process x (httpd)..." So the request was reset to browser.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP 5 the file has to be *php5.ini*

Add these lines in php5.ini

```
post_max_size = 48M
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 192M
```

You can set the sizes to whatever you want.